# Multiple Rows to one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have one tricky problem. (At least for me) I need to get all the values for the rows with the same AdressNrADR on one row instead of multiple. Is their some way to do this?

```
SELECT ADR_Adressen.AdressNrADR, CRM_Aufgaben.TerminVon, LAG_Artikel.ArtikelNrLAG, 
    PRO_Auftraege.Z_R_ckmeldung_Zusatzartikel, CRM_AufgabenLink.MitNrPRO FROM   ( ( ( ( ( ( ADR_Adressen 
    LEFT JOIN  PRO_Auftraege ON ADR_Adressen.AdressNrADR =  PRO_Auftraege.Kunde)  
    LEFT JOIN  CRM_Aufgaben ON PRO_Auftraege.AuftragNrPRO =  CRM_Aufgaben.AuftragNrPRO)  
    LEFT JOIN  CRM_Status ON CRM_Aufgaben.StatusCRM =  CRM_Status.StatusCRM)  
    LEFT JOIN  LAG_Artikel ON CRM_Aufgaben.ArtikelNrLAG =  LAG_Artikel.ArtikelNrLAG)  
    LEFT JOIN  ADR_GruppenLink ON ADR_Adressen.AdressNrADR =  ADR_GruppenLink.AdressNrADR)  
    LEFT JOIN  ADR_Gruppen ON ADR_GruppenLink.GruppeADR =  ADR_Gruppen.GruppeADR)  
    LEFT JOIN  CRM_AufgabenLink ON CRM_Aufgaben.AufgabenNrCRM =  CRM_AufgabenLink.AufgabenNrCRM 
    WHERE { d '2020-02-10'}<=CRM_Aufgaben.TerminVon AND { d '2020-02-16'}+1>=CRM_Aufgaben.TerminBis and CRM_AufgabenLink.MitNrPRO != 0 and CRM_Status.StatusCRM = 1 GROUP BY ADR_Adressen.AdressNrADR,CRM_Aufgaben.TerminVon,CRM_Aufgaben.TerminBis, ADR_Adressen.Name, ADR_Adressen.Vorname, LAG_Artikel.ArtikelNrLAG, LAG_Artikel.Bezeichnung1,CRM_AufgabenLink.MitNrPRO,PRO_Auftraege.Z_R_ckmeldung_Zusatzartikel 
    ORDER BY ADR_Adressen.Name
```

Output now:

```
AdressNrADR TerminVon   ArtikelNrLAG    Z_R_ckmeldung_Zusatzartikel MitNrPRO
13507   2020-02-12 11:00:00.000 7601    7602    2169
13507   2020-02-13 15:00:00.000 7311    NULL    2337
13507   2020-02-14 10:00:00.000 7311    NULL    1028
12955   2020-02-11 08:00:00.000 7311    NULL    1028
12955   2020-02-11 14:00:00.000 3101    NULL    2347
12955   2020-02-13 10:00:00.000 7311    7352    1991
12955   2020-02-13 13:00:00.000 3101    NULL    2347
12955   2020-02-13 14:00:00.000 7311    NULL    1028
10007   2020-02-11 15:00:00.000 7601    7602    1806
10007   2020-02-14 13:00:00.000 7311    NULL    1833
```

Desired Output:

```
AdressNrADR TerminVon1  ArtikelNrLAG1   Z_R_ckmeldung_Zusatzartikel1 MitNrPRO1 TerminVon2   ArtikelNrLAG2   Z_R_ckmeldung_Zusatzartikel2 MitNrPRO2 TerminVon3   ArtikelNrLAG3   Z_R_ckmeldung_Zusatzartikel3 MitNrPRO3
    13507   2020-02-12 11:00:00.000 7601    7602    2169 2020-02-13 15:00:00.000    7311    NULL    2337 2020-02-14 10:00:00.000    7311    NULL    1028
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation and `row_number()`:

```
with cte as (
      <your query here>
     )
select AdressNrADR,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then TerminVon end) as TerminVon1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then ArtikelNrLAG end) as ArtikelNrLAG1,
       . . .
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then TerminVon end) as TerminVon2,
       . . .
from (select cte.*, row_number() over (partition by AdressNrADR order by AdressNrADR) as seqnum
      from cte
     ) t
group by AdressNrADR;
```